# Clustering algorithm with upper bound requirement for each cluster size

Tags: c++, algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I need to do a partition of approximately 50000 points into distinct clusters. There is one requirement: the size of every cluster cannot exceed K. Is there any clustering algorithm that can do this job?

Please note that upper bound, K, of every cluster is the same, say 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [hierarchical K-means](http://gecco.org.chemie.uni-frankfurt.de/hkmeans/H-k-means.pdf), but you keep splitting each cluster which is larger than K, until all of them are smaller.

Another (in some sense opposite approach) would be to use [hierarchical agglomerative clustering](http://www.resample.com/xlminer/help/HClst/HClst_intro.htm), i.e. a bottom up approach and again make sure you don't merge cluster if they'll form a new one of size > K.

Comment: but in agglomerative clustering do we have to calculate all the distances between every pair of points? the time complexity is too high?

Answer (score 2):

Most clustering algorithms can be used to create a tree in which the lowest level is just a single element - either because they naturally work "bottom up" by joining pairs of elements and then groups of joined elements, or because - like K-Means, they can be used to repeatedly split groups into smaller groups.

Once you have a tree, you can decide where to split off subtrees to form your clusters of size <= 100. Pruning an existing tree is often quite easy. Suppose that you want to divide an existing tree to minimise the sum of some cost of the clusters you create. You might have:

```
f(tree-node, list_of_clusters)
{
  cost = infinity;
  if (size of tree below tree-node <= 100)
  {
    cost = cost_function(stuff below tree-node);
  }
  temp_list = new List();
  cost_children = 0;
  for (children of tree_node)
  {
    cost_children += f(child, temp_list);
  }
  if (cost_children < cost)
  {
    list_of_clusters.add_all(temp_list);
    return cost_children;
  }
  list_of_clusters.add(tree_node);
  return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with naive clustering is that you do indeed have to calculate a distance matrix that holds the distance of A from every other member in the set. It depends whether you've pre-processed the population or your amalgamating the clusters into typical individuals then recalculating the distance matrix again.

Comment: i use the euclidean distance between the points. what does statistical significance mean?

Comment: A lack of statistical significance in this case means that you have a load of pretty pictures but you lack anything truely concrete. You generally use clustering to show that a relationship exists which warrants further investigation.

Comment: You could also use clustering to separate observations out into groups so that you could study the groups one by one. If you have one dependent variable per observation you want to predict, you could cluster on the values of the other variables, without showing the clustering algorithm the dependent variable, and then use the cluster structure to help you look for relations between the dependent variables and the independent variable. The clustering algorithm should then be irrelevant to the significance of the connection found.